# How to apply color to lottie-react-native icon

Tags: react-native, icons, animated-gif

I have gone through the complete documentation of `lottie-react-native` but i didn't get any example or description that talks about setting color to an icon. But i finally an issue [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native/pull/584) which suggests as follows,

```
 colorFilters={[{
    keypath: layer,
    color: colorHex
 }]}
```

I am not sure about following things here since I am very new using such a icons,

1.How to find out that how many layers are there in an icon?

2.Is there any property to set single color for whole icon? If so what is it?

Though this question is specific to `lottie-react-native`, I am seeking help here as well. Because if any of our users has already used this package, They may help in this regard.

Thank You.lottie-react-native
Thank you.

Comment: As far as i know you can't change colors dynamically, you can edit the layers and colors on the lottie website though

Comment: @Imjaad I am not getting what are you trying to explain. Can you direct me to that website that you are talking about? .And also Can you have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native/pull/584) which says adding color is supported I presume.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use other library, you can go for vector icons.
Try this library which provides range of icons.
https://youtu.be/BjrlrGy_HaY

This includes installation of vector icons npm package and demonstrates the uses of vector icons library.

Also you can change the size and color of whole icons.

Comment: This "answer" does not answer the question.